# Do native English speakers use a word 'study group'?

Tags: expressions

I have a question. Would you help me?

Do native English speakers use a word 'study group' in real life?

I live in South Korea. And in my country, people join group activities to study English.

And we call that kind of activity as ***'study group'***.

So we say like this, ***"I join several study groups on the weekends."***

But I'm not sure the word study group sounds natural to native English speakers.

I asked my teacher(Korean) and she said I could use a word, ***"English session."***

Or other options are ***"English gathering"*** and ***"English meetup"***.

So which sounds natural to you?

1. English session
2. Englihs gathering
3. English meetup

Comment: Did you look up "study group" in a dictionary?

Comment: Are you talking about the people, or are you talking about the meeting? *Study group* can refer to either, but what synonyms may be used will depend on which concept you are synonymizing.

Comment: I participate in several study groups on the weekend. Sure, study group is used, especially at university level.

Comment: It sounds like you’re using the term with a slightly different meaning than the most common one. Normally, a study group is pooled from the students of a particular course, department, class, year or similar, whereas what you’re describing sounds more like something more ‘public’, advertised and open to anyone. Where I live, such groups are frequently found in libraries and community centres, and I know from my time in Beijing that they’re also very common in China. People might call them study groups, but they’re slightly different from the primary association people have with that term.

Comment: Yes you're right. What I mentioned is not exactly what university students do in the school.  And I was talking about the meeting itself. Anyway thanks everyone for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

**Opinion:** The term "*study group*" is often used by native English speakers and given the alternatives that you've suggested I would say that "*English study group*" would be my preference over all of these. If your intent is to simply indicate participation in a particular time when the study group met I would go with "*English class*" (formally lead by an instructor) or "*English study group session*" (informally directed by the members of the study group)...

Comment: Yes, it is directed by the members of the group. In that case is it okay to use English study group session? Or can I shorten it like session?

Comment: I would "English study group" because "session" has other meaning besides studying.

Comment: Thank you for your kind comment!

Answer (score 0):

There is an American TV series [Community](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Community_(TV_series)), which revolves around people gathering to study Spanish (initially, but their activities quickly grow beyond that). It sounds similar to what you've described, and the characters always refer to this gathering as a "study group".

Comment: Oh thanks. So I can use the word study group. Although it is slightly different. Thanks everyone.